# How to clear all history when user is logout in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

when a user is logout , i want to clear all history and cache . so that user not able to go to back pages.

For these purpose i am use following on login.aspx page :-

```
  if (Request.QueryString["action"] == "logout")
        {

            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Session["CurrentUser"] = null;
            Session["IsJobPoster"] = null;
            Session["AdminEmail"] = null;
            Session["IsAdmin"] = null;
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1d);
            Response.Expires = -1500;
            Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";


    }
```

But user is able to go to back page after logout .

Please suggest me usable link or sample code.

Comment: hrm. usually `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` should do it. There must be more to the story

Comment: I am not sure that you are using Membership provider or not.
If you are, the provider will delete cookies for you and redirect user to login page. Once the user back, the user should be redirect to login page again.   Using Forms Authentication in ASP.NET MVC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049.aspx  and Use Membership in ASP.NET 2.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx.

Comment: You can not erase a client's browser history, this is something controlled by the web browser and is not available to be messed with from the web page.

Answer (score 1):

Also, is there a reason you don't use Session.Abandon() instead? You should consider this, especially if you get more sessionvariables it will be easier to maintain.

Comment: you are right about session , i am using Session.Abandon . But i want also to clear all cache histoy when user logout . redirect to login page with query string action=logout .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about .Net, but, in general using POST and expiring the the page (via appropriate response headers) and using a HTTP redirect should erase the history. Additionally, if, cookie is used to maintain session then overwriting the cookie with some garbage would help too.

Comment: You can not erase a client's history, this is something controlled by the browser.

Comment: I meant the back button history (-1) the page will be expired. Not entire browsing history.

Comment: As I said, you can not remove a back button history element in javascript / from the webpage, at the end of the day this is browser controlled behaviour not site controlled.  Think of all the abuse this would get on spam sites if they coudl remove/alter/read your browser history.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're seeing client-side cached version of the pages.

Move the caching calls (Expires, CacheControl) outside the if-statement. You want them executed at every request so that the pages requiring login wont be cached client-side. The browser will then, when going back in the history, inform the user that the page is invalid/old/outdated and needs to be refreshed. This will initiate a new request which should redirect the user to a login page.

Answer (score 0):

The previous page that the user is able to see after logout is most certainly a page cached in the client. So what you have to do is just write code like this (copied from yours):

```
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Expires = -1500;
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
```

in the pages that are being seen by logged in users so that these are not cached in the browser. Makes sense?

Comment: @Sushant, I don't think you have a problem in your code. The problem is *where* you placed your code. Instead of writing that code in the log out page, you may apply it to your pages that require authentication (e.g. /account/details, /account/profile, etc.). If you apply this code to those pages, then they won't be cached in the browser and so when the user clicks the back button, they will be redirected to the log in page (precisely because there's no cached page in the browser).

Comment: In other words, you don't erase the browser cache on log out. You simply, don't allow the browser to cache your authenticated pages.